# T-SQL : How work a range of time for a specific period inside that range

Tags: sql

I know my title is not very informative but let me explain what I'm trying to do.
Here's the SQL query I'm running on my Oracle server:

```
select 
    median(to_number(TRU.TS_OBJECT.XE2ETIME)) as E2E,
    median(to_number(TRU.TS_OBJECT.XPROCESSTIME)) as Serveur,
    count(to_number(TRU.TS_OBJECT.XE2ETIME)) as hits,
    TRU.TS_OBJECT.CSURISTEM
from 
    tru.ts_object
where
    (TRU.TS_OBJECT.XSTARTTIME >= to_date('2014/01/08 05:30','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI') and TRU.TS_OBJECT.XSTARTTIME < to_date('2014/01/08 21:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI'))
    and TRU.TS_OBJECT.CSMETHOD = 'POST'
    and TRU.TS_OBJECT.SCSTATUS = '200'
Group by 
  TRU.TS_OBJECT.CSURISTEM
```

This query let me find the median for some performance metrics of our web service we exposed to our client. So this give me, for a specific period of time between 5h30 AM to 21h00 PM, the median for this day (2014/01/08).

What a trying to do now is the produced the same output but for a larger period of time, let say 2014/01/01 to 2014/01/29, but always for the data between 5h30 and 21h00 on each day. Right now I'm doing it manually by changing the date range but there's should be a "smarter" way to do this with a select of some sort!?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 ways to do that :

1. Like you are doing manually - write a loop that run your query, each iteration add 1 day to your date (don't know Oracle db to much , in MSSQL it's like this : `DATEADD(day,45,OrderDate)`) , insert each iteration result to table.
2. Write 2 condition in the WHERE, on the dates range, on the hours (like before, in MSSQL it's like this `datepart(hh, date)`)

I think the way to do option 2 in Oracle is like this:

```
where
(TRU.TS_OBJECT.XSTARTTIME >= to_date('2014/01/01 00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI') 
  and TRU.TS_OBJECT.XSTARTTIME < to_date('2014/01/30 00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI'))
and
(EXTRACT (HOUR FROM TRU.TS_OBJECT.XSTARTTIME) >5 
    and EXTRACT (HOUR FROM TRU.TS_OBJECT.XSTARTTIME) < 21 )
```